# How to create a Delta table using Hive statements

Tags: apache-spark, hive, databricks, amazon-athena, delta-lake

I'm trying to save a delta table (from databricks) to be queried with Athena, as they already have support for delta format, the problem is that I can't set a property correctly, it throws an error. My create table statement is:

```
spark.sql(s"""
  |CREATE TABLE $database.$table($dataSchemaAsDDL)
  |ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
  |WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('path'='$path_to_demo_table')
  |STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat'
  |OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveSequenceFileOutputFormat'
  |LOCATION '$path_to_demo_table'
  |TBLPROPERTIES ('classification'='delta','table_type'='delta','delta.lastCommitTimestamp'='$deltaLastCommitTimestamp','delta.lastUpdateVersion'='$deltaLastUpdateVersion','spark.sql.sources.provider'='delta')
  |""".stripMargin
)
```

The problem comes with this property `'spark.sql.sources.provider'='delta'` as databricks says `AnalysisException: Cannot persist database.table into Hive metastore as table property keys may not start with 'spark.sql.': [spark.sql.sources.provider]`

I managed to set this property manually in the glue console, but I find this unpractical

Is there a way to set this property programatically?